# DTM hillshade function error: 'does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name'

Tags: dem, error, hillshade

I am trying to use the hillshade function in QGIS 3.24.2-Tisler. I downloaded a DTM from https://app.pdok.nl/viewer/ as an WMTS. When I try to use the hillshade function I get an error (see below): *"does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name"*. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

---

QGIS version: 3.24.2-Tisler
QGIS code revision: 13c1a028
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.4.2
GEOS version: 3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ version: Rel. 9.0.0, March 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: 1c17a7)
Algorithm started at: 2022-08-01T11:38:16
Algorithm 'Hillshade' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALTITUDE' : 45, 'AZIMUTH' : 315, 'BAND' : 1, 'COMBINED' : False, 'COMPUTE_EDGES' : False, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'crs=EPSG:28992&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=ahn3_05m_dtm&styles=&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:28992&url=https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts/ahn3?request%3DGetCapabilities%26service%3DWMTS%26Version%3D1.0.0', 'MULTIDIRECTIONAL' : False, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/marlo/Desktop/Thesis project/Project/Priority area/Landuse/Breda Landuse/hillshade.tif', 'SCALE' : 1, 'ZEVENBERGEN' : False, 'Z_FACTOR' : 1 }

GDAL command:
gdaldem hillshade "crs=EPSG:28992&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=ahn3_05m_dtm&styles=&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:28992&url=https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts/ahn3?request%3DGetCapabilities%26service%3DWMTS%26Version%3D1.0.0" "C:/Users/marlo/Desktop/Thesis project/Project/Priority area/Landuse/Breda Landuse/hillshade.tif" -of GTiff -b 1 -z 1.0 -s 1.0 -az 315.0 -alt 45.0
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: `crs=EPSG:28992&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=ahn3_05m_dtm&styles=&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:28992&url=https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts/ahn3?request%3DGetCapabilities%26service%3DWMTS%26Version%3D1.0.0' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.  GDALOpen failed - 4`  crs=EPSG:28992&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=ahn3_05m_dtm&styles=&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:28992&url=https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts/ahn3?request%3DGetCapabilities%26service%3DWMTS%26Version%3D1.0.0' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.55 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/marlo/Desktop/Thesis project/Project/Priority '
'area/Landuse/Breda Landuse/hillshade.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/marlo/Desktop/Thesis project/Project/Priority area/Landuse/Breda Landuse/hillshade.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: WM(T)S don't allow you to download the data, they simply display/stream it to your map canvas. Hence you can't run operations on them.

Comment: I suppose that WMS/WMTS layers cannot be used for that purpose. Acquire the DEM as GeoTIFF instead.